# Using Tkinter for a subtitle application, Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create an automatic subtitle writer program to be used for online presentations using Python. Basically, the program will listen to your microphone, and display the words you've said on your screen. This is what I have done so far:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
count = 1
while count <= 5:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print(" ")
    audio = r.listen(source)
try:
    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("{}".format(text))
except:
    print("")
```

Now I know it's not much, but I am trying my best as I'm very, very new to programming. Anyways, I found out an hour ago that Tkinter is a good tool to use for this project, especially when it comes to having the window (where the subtitles are displayed) always on top of your screen. However, I am failing to understand how to properly use it in my case.

So my question is, what should I do to incorporate Tkinter in to my project?

Comment: So your code does work and you just wanna wrap it inside a Tkinter GUI?

Comment: yep, that's exaclty what I want to do